# Wordpress Bitnami MySQL(PhpMyAdmin) reset password on windows

Tags: wordpress, bitnami

I got to work on project using Wordpress Bitnami stack. Original developer does not remember password for root user for MySQL database. I tried to follow the steps on Bitnami website.
https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/apps/wordpress/administration/change-reset-password/

It seems like everything went throught but I am still not able to access the database using root user.

This is whats inside my mysql-init.txt

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
```

Server's response is that this file have been executed but nothing.

I tried to change mysql-init.txt to following

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
CREATE USER 'admin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

After this went throught I am able to access the database using Admin user but my root password does not work. That means file have been executed correctly it just does not update my root password for some reason.

Stack is on Win 10
DB:Distrib 5.7.24, for Win32 on AMD64

Command to run DB with init file:

```
C:\Bitnami\wordpress-4.9.8-2\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file="C:\Bitnami\wordpress-4.9.8-2\mysql\my.ini" --init-file="C:\Bitnami\wordpress-4.9.8-2\mysql\mysql-init.txt" --console
```

Comment: Can you paste the full command which you used to start mysql?

Comment: @Michield'Hont Question updated with requested information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the mysql-init.txt file. Somehow I got a new line at the end of the password.

Very strange issue but hey Its solved.

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass[Here was a new line]';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```